# Date Extraction

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I do want to extract date only from the date column. Actually it is showing as below:-

11/24/2020 00:00:00

I want only 11/24/2020 in redshift database.

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column is a date/time of some sort, you can cast it:

```
select col::date
```

If it is a string, you can use string operations:

```
select left(col, 10)
```